# How to create a frequency table in R from a variable within a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame created within the R console called lungdata. It has six separate variables. I need to create a frequency table from the variable Smoke. Smokers and NonSmokers relative frequency. What would be the correct syntax to create the table. The variables are input as Yes/No.

Comment: `table(lungdata$Smoke)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want relative frequencies, just do

```
prop.table(table(lungdata$smoke))
```

and that should do the trick. If you want counts, not percentages, just use

```
table(lungdata$smoke)
```